# python crash course 19-1 edit posts not working

Tags: python, html, django

This is the error I get when clicking on Edit post under any one of the posts. Would appreciate any help as all this django stuff is confusing me but trying my best to learn. My new post function works and clicking blog/posts to go to the overview page for the blog or to look at all the posts works as well.

NoReverseMatch at /edit_post/1/
Reverse for 'posts' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/$']
Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\seng\Desktop\Python projects\c19\nineteen_one\blogs\templates\blogs\base.html, error at line 0

urls.py

```
"""Defines url paterns for blogs"""

from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'blogs'
urlpatterns =[
    #Home page
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # Page that shows all posts/
    path('posts/', views.posts, name='posts'),
    #Page for adding a new blogpost
    path('new_post/', views.new_post, name='new_post'),
    #Page for editing a post
    #maybe remove the id?
    path('edit_post/<int:post_id>/', views.edit_post, name='edit_post'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import BlogPost
from .forms import BlogPostForm
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    """The home page for blogs"""
    return render(request, 'blogs/index.html')


def posts(request):
    """Show all blogposts"""
    posts = BlogPost.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'posts': posts}
    return render(request, 'blogs/posts.html', context)


def new_post(request):
    """Add a new blogpost"""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        #No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = BlogPostForm()
    else:
    #POST data submitted, process data
        form = BlogPostForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('blogs:posts')

    #Display a blank or invalid form
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'blogs/new_post.html', context)


def edit_post(request, post_id):
    """Edit existing post"""
    post = BlogPost.objects.get(id=post_id)

    if request.method != "POST":
        #Initial request, pre-fill form with the current post
        form = BlogPostForm(instance=post)
    else:
        #Post data submitted, process data
        form = BlogPostForm(instance=post, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('blogs:posts', post_id=post.id)

    context = {'post':post, 'form':form}
    return render(request, 'blogs/edit_post.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import BlogPost

class BlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['text', 'title']
        labels = {'text':'This is the text box', 'title' :"Title here"}
```

edit_post.html

```
{% extends "blogs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <p><a href="{% url 'blogs:posts' post.id %}">{{ post }}</a></p>

  <p>Edit post:</p>

  <form action="{% url 'blogs:edit_post' post.id %}" method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button name="submit">Save changes</button>
  </form>

 {% endblock content %}
```

posts.html

```
{% extends "blogs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <p>Posts</p>

  <ul>
    {% for post in posts %}
      <li>
      <p>{{ post }}</p>
      <p>
        <a href="{% url 'blogs:edit_post' post.id %}">Edit post</a>
      </p>
    </li>
    {% empty %}
      <li>No posts have been added yet.</li>
     {% endfor %}
  </ul>

  <a href="{% url 'blogs:new_post' %}">Add a new post</a>


 {% endblock content %}
```

new_post.html

```
{% extends "blogs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <p>Add a new post:</p>

  <form action="{% url 'blogs:new_post' %}" method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button name="submit">Add post</button>
  </form>


{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: What do you expect `{% url 'blogs:posts' post.id %}` to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with this line in `edit_post.html`:

```
<p><a href="{% url 'blogs:posts' post.id %}">{{ post }}</a></p>
```

If you are editing the post with id 1, then this link is to the url /posts/1. But that has no match in your `urls.py` file.

Either you need to remove the `post.id` parameter from the link, or create a view and a corresponding path in `urls.py` for this link.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help sir! To be frank i never understood what ( 'blogs:posts' post.id) but now I do. Cheers!